# Compact Sets of Random Variables

Tags: probability, general-topology, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $\mathcal{L}^{p}$ the set of $p$-integrable random variables.

Does there exist a compact set $A\subset\mathcal{L}^{1}$? Can you give an example? What about a compact set $A\subset\mathcal{L}^{2}$?

Any comments, ideas, suggestions and references are highly appreciated. Thank you very much!

**EDIT**:
Maybe I should frame this question more explicitly. My apologies.

Let us consider the set
$$\{X\;:\;X\in\mathcal{L}^{1},\;X\geq 0,\;X\leq Y\}$$
with $Y\in\mathcal{L}^{1}$. Is this set compact?

The only approach I could come up with, is to check if Kolmogorov-Riesz applies. But this result already requires $\Omega=[a,b]$...

Comment: Do you just require any compact subset of $\mathcal{L}^1$?

Comment: @NDewolf This question is mainly for self-study. I am trying to wrap my head around the notion of compactness for sets of random variables. Unfortunately I could not come up with any examples in my research so far. Any exmaple of a compact subset of $\mathcal{L}^{1}$ or $\mathcal{L}^{2}$ (with a short explanation or reference) would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Just take any finite subset. This trivially satisfies the condition for topological compactness.

Comment: @NDewolf Fair point! Thanks. I guess this would work, because finite sets are (trivially) totally bounded? Can you think of any "non-degenerate" example. I am thinking about something like $\{X:X\in\mathcal{L}^{p},X\geq Y_{1}, X\leq Y_{2}\}$ with $Y_{1},Y_{2}\in\mathcal{L}^{p}$ and $p=1,2$.

Comment: Yes they are compact because they are complete and totally bounded.

Comment: @NDewolf Thanks for your time and effort. I do see that these sets are complete, since the surrounding spaces are known to be Banach spaces (Riesz-Fischer theorem). But total-boundedness still makes me struggle. Given $\epsilon>0$, is there a straight-forward finite covering of these sets with $\epsilon$-Balls? Or do you have any other convenient sufficient condition in mind?

Comment: My apologies, that last comment was for compactness of the finite sets.